# How to set 'load' action after unsafeWindow.open

Tags: javascript, firefox

It used to be that I could simply do this:

```
var newWindow = unsafeWindow.open(someUrlOnTheSameDomain);
newWindow.addEventListener('load', toRunOnLoad);
// or newWindow.onload = toRunOnLoad;
```

But now Firefox gives the error `Permission denied to access property 'addEventListener'` when trying to perform this or similar actions. This happens whether `window.open` or `unsafeWindow.open` are used.

According to [this announcement](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/comment-page-1/#comment-199873) the new way to interact with an unsafeWindow is to use `cloneInto()`, `exportFunction()`, and `createObjectIn()`, but it's unclear from the announcement or limited documentation how any of these can be used to attach an event handler to the new window.

What's the new solution for this pattern?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, I never found a good solution and ended up opting for having my javascript create an iframe in the current window so that I could continue to interact with the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. Turns out interacting with a window opened from another window via a content script is really a mess.

1. You can use `window.open`, but cannot interact with the resulting window, because of the various involved wrappers in conjunction with the sandbox principal (same origin policy).
2. You can use `unsafeWindow.open`, but need to make sure to provide a function belongs to `unsafeWindow`.

So I experimented a bit, and this seems to work in Firefox 31 and Nightly.

`main.js`

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.mozilla.org",
    contentScriptFile: require("sdk/self").data.url("script.js")
});
```

`script.js`

```
function doSomething(e) {
  var d = e.target.ownerDocument || e.target;
  var w = d.defaultView;
  console.log("abc", d.location.href, w.document.title, d.body.innerHTML);
}
exportFunction(doSomething, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "doSomething"});

var w = unsafeWindow.open("http://www.mozilla.org/about");
w.addEventListener('load', unsafeWindow.doSomething);
```